# Wie heißt die Konstruktion, in der zwei Phrasen im gleichen Fall nebeneinander stehen, um "von etwas" zu bedeuten

Tags: grammatical-case

Wie heist der Name der Struktur, in der ein Nomen in einem anderen Fall als Genitiv verwendet wird, um den Fall der Phrase zu beschreiben, die ihn beschreibt. Es sind zwei Substantive, die im selben Fall nebeneinander gestellt sind. Würde das die Konstruktion "ein bisschen Musik" erklären? Anstatt *eine Tasse von heißem Wasser* zu sagen, sagt man *eine Tasse heißes Wasser*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Konstruktion "ein Glas Wasser" nennt man eine [*partitive Apposition*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Partitive-33869), bei der eine Maß- oder Mengenangabe mit einem Substantiv verknüpft wird.

Diese Form gibt es sowohl **mit** als auch **ohne** Kasusangleichung (das Substantiv nimmt den Kasus der Maßangabe an), es ist also sowohl erlaubt

> den Kuchen backe ich mit einem bisschen gerösteten Nüssen

(Die *Nüsse* nehmen den Dativ des "Bisschens" an)

als auch (*Nüsse* im Nominativ)

> den Kuchen backe ich mit einem bißchen geröstete Nüsse

zu sagen. Die erste Form mit Kasusanpassung hört sich für mich allerdings "richtiger" an.

Damit's ein bißchen komplizierter wird, darf man auch noch einen partitiven Genitiv (das Substantiv, von dem das Maß genommen wird, steht im Genitiv) verwenden, auch das ist richtig, aber eher gehobener Ausdruck und nicht sehr verbreitet

> den Kuchen backe ich mit einem bißchen gerösteter Nüsse

Answer (score 3):

Die Konstruktion

> <del>eine Tasse von heißem Wasser</del>

ist falsch.

---

### Genitivus Partitivus

Die übliche Art, das auszusagen, was mit obiger Konstruktion gemeint ist, ist der *Genitivus Partitivus* (Genitiv der Anteil-Beziehung):

> eine Tasse *heißen Wassers*
>   Irene bestellte nur **eine Tasse heißen Wassers,** das Tee-Säckchen hatte sie selbst mitgebracht.

Irene bestellt hier also eine Tasse, und diese Tasse soll mit heißem Wasser gefüllt sein.

Andere Beispiele für den Genitivus Partitivus sind:

> ein Rudel *hungriger Wölfe*
>   ein Strauß *roter Rosen*

---

### Maß- und Mengenangaben

Irene, aus dem obigen Beispiel, könnte anstelle einer Tasse (mit einer bestimmten Eigenschaft) auch Wasser bestellen. Dann müsste sie aber angeben, wie viel Wasser sie haben will, und das geht so:

> Irene bestellte nur **eine Tasse heißes Wasser,** das Tee-Säckchen hatte sie selbst mitgebracht.

Jetzt steht das heiße Wasser in Akkusativ, und es käme auch ohne die Tasse aus:

> Irene bestellte nur **heißes Wasser,** ...

Die Tasse ist hier nämlich eine Beifügung zum Wasser. Oben, beim Genitivus Qualitatis war es ja umgekehrt. Dort was das Wasser eine Beifügung zur Tasse.

Das Wasser könnte in einem anderen Kontext aber auch im Nominativ stehen:

> **Eine Tasse heißes Wasser** steht schon auf dem Tisch.

Bei Maßen denkt man zuerst natürlich an Meter, Kilogramm, Liter und ähnliche Wörter:

> Walter kaufte **dreißig Meter Fallschirmseide.**
>   Im Sack waren **25 Kilo Äpfel.**

Aber ebenso üblich sind Hohlmaße aus dem Alltag:

> Man gebe **vier Esslöffel Zucker** in den Teig.
>   Barbara gab jedem Schüler genau **einen Schöpfer Suppe.**

Und die Tasse eignet sich als Hohlmaß ebenso gut:

> Natalie hat heute schon **fünf Tassen Kaffee** getrunken.
>   Eugen goss **eine Tasse Wasser** in das Blumenbeet.

Das Gut, das abgemessen wird, kann natürlich durch Attribute noch näher bestimmt sein:

> Barbara gab jedem Schüler **einen Schöpfer *klare* Suppe.**
>   Man gebe **vier Esslöffel *geschälte* Mandeln** in den Teig.

Und natürlich ebenso:

> Irene bestellte nur **eine Tasse heißes Wasser,** das Tee-Säckchen hatte sie selbst mitgebracht.

---

### bisschen

Man kann auch das Wort *»Bissen«* als Maß verwenden (Ein Bissen ist die Menge, die man mit einem Biss von einer Speise abbeißt):

> Ich habe erst **einen Bissen Brot** gegessen.

Das geht auch, ohne tatsächlich etwas abzubeißen:

> Auf dem Teller lag nur mehr **ein Bissen Brot.**

Wenn dieser Bissen besonders klein ist, kann man das durch die Umwandlung in ein Diminutiv kennzeichnen:

> Auf dem Teller lag nur mehr **ein *Bisschen* Brot.**

Aber bei diesem Diminutiv denkt man nicht mehr an seine Herkunft vom Wort *»Bissen«*, außerdem verwendet man es auch im Zusammenhang mit Dingen, die man gar  nicht beißen kann:

> Ich gebe dir noch **ein *bisschen* Zeit.**
>   Ich höre **ein *bisschen* Musik.**

In dieser Verwendung wird das Wort nicht mehr als Substantiv interpretiert, sondern als Indefinitpronomen. Das ist auch der Grund, warum man es nun klein schreibt.

Unter den Indefinitpronomen nimmt es aber eine Ausnahmestellung ein, weil es immer zusammen mit dem Zahlwort *ein* oder eine weiteren Indefinitpronomen, nämlich *kein* verwendet wird:

> Ich höre **viel** Musik.
>   Ich höre **etwas** Musik.
>   Ich höre **jede** Musik.

aber:

> Ich höre ***ein* bisschen** Musik.
>   Er hatte ***kein* bisschen** Ehrgefühl im Leib.

Comment: "Ein Glas Wasser" ist kein Genitivus Qualitatis, sondern ein Genitivus Partitivus. "Eine Fahrkarte zweiter Klasse" oder "Ein Mann der Tat" wären tatsächlich Beispiele für ersteres. Ob "ein Glas von Wasser" tatsächlich so falsch ist ? Wenn es *aus* Wasser wäre, möglicherweise nicht (siehe "Ein Kästchen von Ebenholz" als archaisches Beispiel aus dem Märchen). Aber gemeint ist natürlich was anderes. Und: So schön sie ist - leider beantwortet deine Antwort die Frage nicht.

Comment: @tofro "ein Glas von Wasser" wäre aber eher "ein Glas aus Wasser gemacht"? Sollte es dann nicht besser "ein Glas mit Wasser" heissen? Allerdings liegt die Betonung hier wohl eher auf das Wasser, nicht auf das Gefäß, so daß "ein Glas Wasser" eher "etwas Wasser im Glas" ist, als "ein Glas mit Wasser"

Comment: @tofro: »Ein Glas Wasser« ist überhaupt kein Genitiv. Das ist eine schöde Mengenangabe. Genitiv wäre »ein Glas Wassers« mit s am Ende von *Wassers*. Wie kommst du auf die Idee, »ein Glas Wasser« könnte Genitiv sein? Genau diesen Unterschied zwischen Genitiv und Mengenangaben habe ich in meiner Antwort ja thematisiert.

Comment: Tippfehler. da fehlt ein "s", sorry. Es geht um deine Behauptung nach dem ersten Strich.

Comment: @tofro, ja dann hast du recht. Ich bessere das aus

Comment: Sind „eine Tasse von heißem Wasser“ und „eine Tasse heißen Wassers“ nicht bedeutungsgleich (sofern man das von irgendwelchen zwei Ausdrücken behaupten kann)? Kann man den Genitiv nicht immer (auch, wenn es nicht unseren Hörgewohnheiten entspricht) durch eine Präpositionalkonstruktion ersetzen?

Comment: @Philipp: Kommentare sind der falsche Ort, solche Fragen zu stellen. Das ist ein besserer Ort dafür: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask